# Getting the data for a pie chart

Tags: python, django

Say, I have a model that defines a Car and one of its field is 'manufacturer'. For example:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    licence_plate = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    .
    .
    .
```

To draw a pie chart showing the totals for the various manufacturers (using matplotlib) I need two lists. One containing the  manufacturer totals and the other the corresponding manufacture names. So I would like to end up with something like this.

```
[516, 122, 131, 125, ...
['Ford','BMW','Mazda','Honda', ...
```

By the way, I don't know the names of the manufacturers beforehand.

One more thing, I only want to show the top 5 manufacturers. All the others should be lumped in a manufacturer named 'Other'.

How can I get these lists?

Comment: How is the data stored originally?

Comment: You haven't said where you should get the numbers for the totals from. Is that stored in another attribute of Car? Or do you count the number of cars?

Comment: @Tim I've udpated the question.

Comment: @lazyr Yes, need to look at all the cars in the db and tally up the totals for each manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is quite correct, but you need something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum

num_taken = 5  # modify this if you want more/less than 5
query = Car.objects.values('manufacturer').annotate(num_cars=Count('manufacturer')).order_by('-num_cars')
top_cars = query[:num_taken]
others = query[num_taken:].aggregate(total=Sum('num_cars'))['total']
car_nums = [entry['num_cars'] for entry in top_cars] + [others]
car_manufactureres = [entry['manufacturerer'] for entry in top_cars] + ['Others']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close. However, I don't want to ignore the total for the manufacturers that aren't in the top 5. I want to put all those below the top 5 in a separate group called 'Other'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure python (you deal with the django stuff) solution. I've made myself some car objects to test the code on.

```
from random import choice
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

manufacturers = ["Ford", "BMW", "Mazda", "Honda", "Volvo", "Saab", "Toyota"]
cars = [type("Car", (object,), {"manufacturer": choice(manufacturers)})
    for x in range(1000)]

count = defaultdict(int)
for car in cars:
    count[car.manufacturer] += 1

top = sorted(count.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
other = sum(x[1] for x in top[5:])
list1 = [x[0] for x in top[:5]] + ["other"]
list2 = [x[1] for x in top[:5]] + [other]

print list1
print list2
```